# does $Aut^0$ act trivially on the Neron-Severi group?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-groups, cohomology

Let $X$ be a projective   integral scheme over an algebraically closed field $k$. Does $\mathrm{Aut}^0_{X/k}(k)$ act trivially on $NS(X)$?

Comment: Yes. $NS(X)$ is a finitely generated abelian group. The homomorphism $\operatorname{Aut}(X)\rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(NS(X))  $ is algebraic, it maps a connected subgroup to the identity.

Comment: The question's already answered, but it's perhaps worth mentioning the more interesting direction: the kernel of $\operatorname{Aut}(X) \to \operatorname{Aut}(NS(X))$ is an algebraic group, in the sense of having only finitely many components.  So something that acts trivially is almost in $\operatorname{Aut}^0$ (e.g. some positive iterate is in $\operatorname{Aut}^0(X)$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as abx already said. The morphism $\mathrm{Aut}(X) \to \mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{NS}(X))$ is  algebraic. Thus, it maps the connected component of the algebraic group $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ to the **trivial** connected component of $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{NS}(X))$. QED